# Is there a way to use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW without unpacking the buffer (C++/CLR)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio

A software I am writing is about to take an action that requires the current logged in user is actually the one taking the action. So I want to have windows just ask for the current user's password or biometrics or whatever before the action is allowed to continue.

I used an interop for UserConsentVerifier from another post (Code Below).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Security.Credentials.UI;

namespace UWPInterop
{
    //MIDL_INTERFACE("39E050C3-4E74-441A-8DC0-B81104DF949C")
    //IUserConsentVerifierInterop : public IInspectable
    //{
    //public:
    //    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RequestVerificationForWindowAsync(
    //        /* [in] */ HWND appWindow,
    //        /* [in] */ HSTRING message,
    //        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
    //        /* [iid_is][retval][out] */ void** asyncOperation) = 0;
    //};
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("39E050C3-4E74-441A-8DC0-B81104DF949C")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InterfaceType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIInspectable)]
    public interface IUserConsentVerifierInterop
    {
        IAsyncOperation<UserConsentVerificationResult> RequestVerificationForWindowAsync(IntPtr appWindow, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.HString)] string Message, [In] ref Guid riid);
    }

    //Helper to initialize UserConsentVerifier
    public static class UserConsentVerifierInterop
    {
        public static IAsyncOperation<UserConsentVerificationResult> RequestVerificationForWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, string Message)
        {
            IUserConsentVerifierInterop userConsentVerifierInterop = (IUserConsentVerifierInterop)WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(typeof(UserConsentVerifier));
            Guid guid = typeof(IAsyncOperation<UserConsentVerificationResult>).GUID;

            return userConsentVerifierInterop.RequestVerificationForWindowAsync(hWnd, Message, ref guid);

        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if a Windows Hello is setup. It returns DeviceNotPresent when its not or similar errors. Trying to find an alternative where the windows password is provided instead. This code works but I'm not entirely happy with the fact I am using a password in the app's memory. (C++/CLR)

```
bool ValidateUser(String ^caption, String ^message)
    {
        bool result = false;

        String^ userName = WindowsIdentity::GetCurrent()->Name;

        std::wstring strUsername = marshal_as<std::wstring>(userName);
        std::wstring strCaption = marshal_as<std::wstring>(caption);
        std::wstring strMessage = marshal_as<std::wstring>(message);

        CREDUI_INFOW info;

        ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));

        info.cbSize = sizeof(info);

        info.pszMessageText = strMessage.c_str();
        info.pszCaptionText = strCaption.c_str();


        ULONG authPackage = 0;

        LPVOID pOut;
        ULONG bufSize;

        DWORD inBuffer = 0;
        std::vector<uint8_t> credBuffer;

        if (!CredPackAuthenticationBufferW(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, (LPWSTR)strUsername.c_str(), L"", NULL, &inBuffer)
        && ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == ::GetLastError())
        {
            credBuffer.resize(inBuffer);

            if (!CredPackAuthenticationBufferW(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, (LPWSTR)strUsername.c_str(), L"", credBuffer.data(), &inBuffer))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        DWORD dwResult = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(&info, 0, &authPackage, credBuffer.data(), inBuffer, &pOut, &bufSize, NULL, CREDUIWIN_GENERIC | CREDUIWIN_IN_CRED_ONLY);
        if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            DWORD dwUserLength = 0;
            DWORD dwDomainLength = 0;
            DWORD dwPasswordLength = 0;

            try
            {
                if (!::CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, pOut, bufSize, nullptr, &dwUserLength, nullptr, &dwDomainLength, nullptr, &dwPasswordLength)
                    && ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == ::GetLastError())
                {
                    std::vector<wchar_t> bufferUser(dwUserLength);
                    std::vector<wchar_t> bufferDomain(dwDomainLength);
                    std::vector<wchar_t> bufferPassword(dwPasswordLength);
                    if (::CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, pOut, bufSize, bufferUser.data(), &dwUserLength, bufferDomain.data(), &dwDomainLength, bufferPassword.data(), &dwPasswordLength))
                    {
                        HANDLE hToken;

                        std::wstring strUsername = bufferUser.data();
                        std::wstring strDomain;

                        if (bufferDomain.size() == 0)
                        {
                            std::wstring::size_type pos = strUsername.find(L'\\');
                            if (pos != std::wstring::npos)
                            {
                                strDomain = strUsername.substr(0, pos);
                                strUsername = strUsername.substr(pos + 1, strUsername.size() - pos - 1);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strDomain = bufferDomain.data();
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            if (::LogonUserW(strUsername.c_str(), strDomain.c_str(), bufferPassword.data(), LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
                                result = true;
                        }
                        catch (...) // Catch so memory can be cleared
                        {

                        }

                        ClearBuffer(bufferUser.data(), dwUserLength);
                        ClearBuffer(bufferDomain.data(), dwDomainLength);
                        ClearBuffer(bufferPassword.data(), dwPasswordLength);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(...)  // Catch so memory can be cleared
            {
            }

            ClearBuffer(pOut, bufSize);
            CoTaskMemFree(pOut);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there a way to use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW without unpacking the buffer it returns to verify the login?

Comment: Sure, there is. It depends on who's responsible for telling you that the current user entered valid credentials. You should edit your question and include what you've already tried, also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So you want the user to trust you and give the username/password to your application when you don't trust the user. You can use [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) through P/Invoke, but that's feel-good security. Looks good but is essentially pointless and in *this* case, *EXTREMELY* dangerous. Who's going to prevent a hacker from emulating your app and steal passwords? How are *you* going to prevent keyloggers from stealing the credentials? You asked for them, it's your responsibility now.

Comment: When Windows asks for a passwor or PIN, or when it asks for consent through the UAC screen, it uses a *separate, isolated* desktop that can't be accessed by anyone else. When UWP applications in Windows 10 ask for verification, they use an OS service too, through [UserConsentVerifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier). If you want real security you should use this class to ask for verification instead of handling the user's credentials yourself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UserConsentVerifier is what I am looking for but it's UWP and not WPF. Any other method?

Comment: You can use UWP APIs and controls from WPF, especially in the latest Windows 10 versions. MS realized that developers won't migrate to UWP anytime soon. Check [Host UWP XAML controls in desktop apps (XAML Islands)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) for example. Even if you can't use the API directly, you could create a UWP control and use it inside your application.

Comment: Also check [Tutorial: Modernize a WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/modernize-wpf-tutorial). As a worst-case scenario, [check this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74d60a77-5c60-4ab6-840f-5058e8a53925/userconsentverifier-from-wpf?forum=wpf). In the end, someone shows how to use  UserConsentVerifier through interop

Comment: Thanks for the responses!

Comment: You want a validate windows to check the current logged user is actually the one taking the action.   
So, if the logged user is your windows user, you can use the Environment.UserName Property  to get the user name of the person who is currently logged in the operating system, and pop-up a window and ask user to input password to validate.[C# Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01da4335-862d-40e7-8bf6-9df8b158c751/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @Yohann Validating a user with username/password isn't hard. The problem is that doesn't use secure desktop or the user's login provider (Pin, biometrics, etc).

Comment: You can refer the Panagiotis Kanavos's suggestion. If you want to use biometrics, maybe you need to call services to validate.